# Unhandled exception at 0x71002A95 (SDL2_ttf.dll)

Tags: c++, sdl-2, truetype, unhandled-exception

I've been writing some rudimentary code in C++ with the SDL2 library. It was working flawlessly, but I needed to print some text on screen, and to do that, I had to download the SDL2 TTF library. I installed it just like I did with SDL2. I tried to simply print a word, but once I compile the code, Visual Studio says the following:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x71002A95 (SDL2_ttf.dll) in nuevo proyecto.exe: 
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

And the program just doesn't work, it's frozen in a white screen (it worked with no problems before I tried to use the TTF library). What can I do? Thanks in advance. Here's my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include <string>

SDL_Window * ventana;
SDL_Surface * superficie;
SDL_Surface * alpha;
SDL_Surface * renderizar;
SDL_Surface * texto;
bool inicia = false, cierra=false;
SDL_Point mouse;
TTF_Font *fuente = TTF_OpenFont("arial.ttf", 20);
char* palabras="hola";
SDL_Color color = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };

int controles(){
    SDL_GetMouseState(&mouse.x,&mouse.y);
    return 0;
}

int graficos(char *archivo){ //la primera vez inicia ventana
    //el argumento es el nombre del bmp a renderizar
    if (inicia == false){ ventana = SDL_CreateWindow("ventana", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480, 0); } //abre ventana solo una vez
    inicia = true; // no permite que se abra mas de una vez la ventana
    superficie = SDL_GetWindowSurface(ventana);
    alpha = SDL_LoadBMP("alpha.bmp");
    texto = TTF_RenderText_Solid(fuente, palabras, color);
    renderizar = SDL_LoadBMP(archivo);
    SDL_Rect rectangulo = { 0, 0, 640, 480 };
    SDL_Rect rrenderizar = { mouse.x, mouse.y, 4, 4 };
    SDL_Rect rtexto = { 0, 0, 60, 60 };
    SDL_BlitSurface(alpha, NULL, superficie, &rectangulo);
    SDL_BlitSurface(renderizar, NULL, superficie, &rrenderizar);
    SDL_BlitSurface(texto, NULL, superficie, &rtexto);
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(ventana);
    return 0;
}   

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    TTF_Init();
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Event evento;
    while (!cierra){
        SDL_PollEvent(&evento);
        switch (evento.type){
        case SDL_QUIT:cierra = true; break;
        }
        //programa aqui abajo
        controles();
        graficos("hw.bmp");
    }
    TTF_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

PS: I do have the DLL's, fonts and other files in the Debug folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [SDL_TTF Documentation](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf_8.html#SEC8):

> ```
> int TTF_Init()
> ```
>
> Initialize the truetype font API. *This must be called
>   before using other functions in this library*, except TTF_WasInit. SDL
>   does not have to be initialized before this call.

You call `TTF_OpenFont` before calling `TTF_Init` when declaring your font variable. Instead you should do:

```
TTF_Font* fuente = NULL;    
int main()
{
    TTF_Init();
    fuente = TTF_OpenFont("arial.ttf", 20);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm :)